# Added the Intel Multi-OS Engine module to LibGDX, but there is an issue

Tags: android

I added the module "Intel Multi-OS Engine" to my Android based project that is using the LibGDX library. I was under the impression that this was a replacement to RoboVM (or at least an alternative to). I add the Intel Multi-OS Engine module and it basically gives me a sample project of an airplane within my large Java + Android game. I thought, or at least can't really tell, that this module would take my existing Android Java project and allow it to deploy to iOS via an Xcode transfer.

When I added the application/desktop app to my Android project, it was very easy to run it on my desktop. Does "Intel Multi-OS Engine" basically have no connection to my existing Java Android project and I need to recreated it things in the iOS module instead of tapping into what I already have?